# Am I translating correctly?

Tags: listening

see this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ndEjFzKqTk), at **0:51**, it seems that the lady said
"***but down in the middle there’s a path they’re not touching***"

It is very hard for me to translate that saying.

so, **Am I translating correctly?**

Comment: ...but down the middle there's a passage where it's not touching. This is where the air comes.

Comment: P.S. You're not "translating", you're *hearing*.

Comment: *Transcribing* is probably the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Down the middle* versus *Down in the middle* :

**A yellow line runs *down the middle* of the road.**

***Down in the middle* of the arena, the gladiator was fighting a lion.**